# Failed to start namenode: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby

Tags: java, kubernetes, hadoop, hdfs

seeing this issue in Apache Hadoop 3.3.3 HA setup in kubernetes.
namenode is running in active NN , but failing in standby NN as shown below

```
$ hdfs --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR namenode -bootstrapStandby  -nonInteractive
```

```
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode","time":1659634227271,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,271","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]"}
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode","time":1659634227387,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,387","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"createNameNode [-bootstrapStandby]"}
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby","time":1659634227698,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,698","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"Found nn: apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.backend.svc.cluster.local, ipc: hdfs:8020"}
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode","time":1659634227698,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,698","level":"ERROR","thread":"main","message":"**Failed to start namenode**.","exceptionclass":"java.io.IOException","stack":["java.io.IOException: java.lang.**NullPointerException**","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.**ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:549)**","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.**NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1741)**","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.**NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1834)**","Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.**parseConfAndFindOtherNN**(BootstrapStandby.java:435)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:114)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:95)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:544)","\t... 2 more"]}
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil","time":1659634227702,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,702","level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException"}
{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode","time":1659634227714,"date":"2022-08-04 17:30:27,714","level":"INFO","thread":"shutdown-hook-0","message":"SHUTDOWN_MSG: \n/************************************************************\nSHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at apache-hadoop-namenode-1.apache-hadoop-namenode.backend.svc.cluster.local }
```

can anybody help the reason for this error.

Comment: does standby NN use http port 9870 or hdfs port 8020 ?

Comment: There's probably no solution because HDFS is not designed to run in k8s... Meanwhile Hadoop Ozone, is

Comment: @OneCricketeer hmm, I don’t think there is any problem for HDFS to run on kubernetes, Salesforce had a blog as well on that: https://engineering.salesforce.com/hadoop-hbase-on-kubernetes-and-public-cloud-part-i-1a85a77c64ec/?source=friends_link&sk=c0d01bf39c62f0d7030dd298ccdf339f

Comment: @AyushSaxena Just because people manage to get it working doesn't mean it was _designed for it_. In any case, question should include relevant XML config files

Comment: Thanks for everybodys comment,
was finally able to resolve this after removing hdfs in hdfs://${HOSTNAME}:8020 for rpc-address in hdfs-site.xml